# Boot Order not found

Tags: windows, bootloader

Hi I am facing a problem regarding booting of my device when I turn on my pc and after bios boots up there is a error shown up as boot order not found and the system gets stuck in boot loop what should I do
I have windows 11 dual boot
HDD with nvme
Both are with windows 11 boot

I tried restarting and changing boot option to nvme but it showed no boot option available choose a USB key or hard drive to boot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually there is a error showing when i boot up my system which says" system boot order not found initializing defaults" and i don't know how to exactly fix it

Comment: Saying that there is no boot order usually means either your disk boot information is corrupted, or BIOS settings doesn't see/set your disk as default boot option. 

Was it booting before? Did you connected NVMe disk from another PC? Check MB manufacturer web site for default setting.